# Qualified double not displayed properly

Tags: c#, .net, properties, double

I'm trying to make some controls which size would be set using qualified double so that the control size are the same no matter which screen it's displayed on.

So I have this converter which converts double to qualified double:

```
double effectiveValue = cm;
string qualifiedDouble = effectiveValue + "cm";
LengthConverter lc = new LengthConverter();
double converted = (double)lc.ConvertFrom(qualifiedDouble);
```

The problem is that it's not really efficient regarding the system parameters such as resolution or the default system zooming (idk how it's called in English)

[image]

Do you have any clue on how it may be possible to have the exact same values in centimeters displayed on any screen for any resolution, any zoom settings and so on.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to size your GUI components to centimetres as measured by a ruler placed up to your monitor, it just can't be done unfortunately.

Comment: So what are the purpose of qualified double in this case: Width="20cm" ? @keith

Comment: I guess WPF converts cm to pixels using the current DPI (dots per inch). The main problem is DPI on computer screens is not a physical measure like it is for, say, printers. Might be worth googling the history behind DPI for computer displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a way to do so using the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) which contains the sufficient informations on displays that were connected to the computer. The EDID are stored in a registry:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\\DISPLAY\ + displayId + registryId
```

Here is the code to retrieve the ratio that will convert the cm to pixel on screen

```
public static double GetCmToPixelRatio()
{
    var diagVector = GetActiveDisplayDiag();

    var width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    return width / diagVector.X;
}


public static int GetDPIX()
{
    var dpiXProperty = typeof(SystemParameters).GetProperty("DpiX", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    return (int)dpiXProperty.GetValue(null, null);

}

private static Point GetActiveDisplayDiag()
{
    //get active display
    string wmiQuery = string.Format("Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor");

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            //get display id
            string regPath = (string)retObject.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID");
            if (regPath != null)
            {
                var pathInfo = regPath.Split('\\');
                var displayId = pathInfo[1];
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\DISPLAY\\" + displayId);
                var firstSubReg = reg.GetSubKeyNames()[0];
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(firstSubReg + "\\Device Parameters");
                var edid = (byte[])reg.GetValue("EDID");
                return new Point(edid[21], edid[22]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
    return new Point();
}
```

Using that I created my converter:

```
public class CmToPixelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    double ratio = DisplayHelper.GetCmToPixelRatio();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value * ratio;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting! If I may, I've got some questions - do you do any matching of the screen and your application's windows? I mean, I see here that you use "ActiveScreen" but how does that corellate to the actual screen your application's windows are located? I assume you are using second monitor as "extra extended desktop space", so I'd think "active" may be either of screens and the window may sit on the other and screw the calculations? oh, and do you have any issues i.e. when dragging a window to the second monitor? maybe it's all OK and I'm wrong, but the code looks a bit too simple

Comment: My application is hosted on a computer which won't allow multiscreen and is gonna be fullscreen all the times which helps a lot. But still I think the things you pointed out can be handled with pinvoke calls with Windows handle

Answer (score 3):

It should (mostly) work, I've done similar things few times, but you need to ensure that in your desktop appearance settings (and graphic card settings, presentation profiles etc - if you have any such software) you have all the scaling disabled (set to 100% normal, no big fonts etc). I belive that's the "system zooming" you mentioned.

After setting it to 100%, all WPF units should display the same on any screen. So 10x10rectangle (or 10cmx10cm) on all screens should look the same. If you use qualified, then it should look the same on any resolution. In theory, or rather, in OperatingSystem's point of view.

The problem is, even if the OS is 100% sure that all is calculated well, still some card/monitor configurations can "lie" to the OS about their capabilities. You can't get actual DPIs from i.e. a wall projector. Some monitors with wierd dimensions can scale the image and will distort the image horizontally or vertically to fill the whole screen so no black margins will apear. Software drivers of your graphics card can do that too, internally, so OS will not know it. And WPF's DPIs, device-independent-units and qualified-lengths are all about what system knows and how's that related to the real screen.

However, if you ensure that all system-scaling, screen-filling, 16:9/4:3 translations, etc are disabled, than you can mostly expect it to be displayed correctly. You can't escape from having the users configure that. Once they do that, they can verify the results with some simple "ruler" screen that your app will display. If it's still wrong, then that's mostly to blame on the hardware, and you're stuck. It will need to be changed if user really wants to have it running.

btw. I have not found any way to **consitently** handle "system zooming", that is a weird part of the OS display. It seems easy at first, just read the settings from registry/etc and scale up/down accordingly, but then, it turns out that on **different OS versions** (like i.e. winXP vs win7) that scaling works a little differently.. maybe you will find a way, I have not. I just asked users to set to 100%. Or to change the hardware, because when they had it set on non-100% already then it almost always indicated that their gpu/monitor had weird resolutions had some "smart software" that did some extra scaling..

Comment: Thanks for your answer quetzalcoatl, it partially answers my problem but still it helps. Cheers